# dc.js: dynamically multiple dimensions

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create as many dimensions as I got datasets in the array. The dataset amount is variable. In my example i have 3 but it can be more or less.

My data:

```
signalData: {
signal1: {
  name: "",
  data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
},
signal2: {
  name: "",
  data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
},
signal3: {
  name: "",
  data: {2,3,1,4,5,1,3},
},
```

I tried this:

```
var cf = crossfilter(flatData);

  var dimension = cf.dimension(dc.pluck("key"));
  var group = [];

  for (var signal in this.signalData) {
    dim = null;
    var dim = dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
      return d[signal];
    });

    group.push(dim);
  }
```

But all 3 rendered charts only display the data of the signal3

Comment: This is a common JavaScript pitfall. Please check this item in the dc.js FAQ:https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-a-function-i-created-in-a-loop-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an easier solution to the [entry in the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-a-function-i-created-in-a-loop-not-work).

[Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is often a good solution, because the value for the current iteration of the loop will be captured in a local variable which won't change:

```
  Object.keys(signalData).forEach(function(signal) {
    dim = null;
    var dim = dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
      return d[signal];
    });

    group.push(dim);
  });
```

Here we use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the field names, and then loop over that using `forEach`.

(I don't use for loops all that much, for this reason.)